# How to make folder as image database?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How to make folder as image database,i am inserting a images to a folder and processing one by one images in a folder(Here i am capturing images from camera and dumping that images to a folder, simultaneously i am processing the dumped images one by one).Is there any solution is available?

Comment: that makes no sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: Could you clarify your post, please

Comment: i am  not using any database here.....instead if database i am using folder, the folder contains images.

Comment: So you want to add images to the folder by code .. like uploading maybe ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.IO; 
... 
foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.jpeg")) 
{     
    //do the job 
}
```

Comment: i tried this.but i am getting following error  " 'System.IO.Directory' does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateFiles' "

Comment: Yup, use get files then. Most probably you are using different .NET framework.

Comment: not surprising enumeratefiles method only available in .net 4.0, .net 4.5, & SilverLight http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx